# How to write just the `row` value of a DataFrame to a file in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `dataframe` that has just one column, whose value is a JSON string. I'm trying to write just the values to a file with one record per line.

```
scala> selddf.printSchema
root
 |-- raw_event: string (nullable = true)
```

The data looks like this:

```
scala> selddf.show(1)
+--------------------+
|           raw_event|
+--------------------+
|{"event_header":{...|
+--------------------+
only showing top 1 row
```

I am running the following to save it to file:

```
selddf.select("raw_event").write.json("/data/test")
```

The output looks like:

```
{"raw_event":"{\"event_header\":{\"version\":\"1.0\"...}"}
```

I would like the output to just say:

```
{\"event_header\":{\"version\":\"1.0\"...}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is that when you write a json you are writing the dataframe in which the column is raw_event.

Your first option is to simply write it as text:

```
df.write.text(filename)
```

Another option (if your json schema is constant to all elements) is using the from_json function to convert this to a legal dataframe. Select the elements (the content of the column which would include all members of the json) and only then save it:

```
val df = Seq("{\"a\": \"str\", \"b\": [1,2,3], \"c\": {\"d\": 1, \"e\": 2}}").toDF("raw_event")
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField("a", StringType), StructField("b", ArrayType(IntegerType)), StructField("c", StructType(Seq(StructField("d", IntegerType), StructField("e", IntegerType))))))
df.withColumn("jsonData", from_json($"raw_event", schema)).select("jsonData.*").write.json("bla.json")
```

The advantage of the second option is that you can test for maleformed rows (which would result in null) and therefore you can add a filter to remove them.

Note that in both cases you don't have escaping for the ". If you want that you would need to use the first option and first do a UDF which adds the escaping.